# Scrolling of modal window Bootstrap to bottom

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a modal window Bootstrap with dynamic height (more than height of screen). How can I scroll the window to bottom programmatically? I tried to do this:

```
$('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal').height() }, 500);
```

But variable $('#modal').height() is not changing while I'm resizing window.
Any ideas?

Comment: Please try to add overflow: hidden; to the body, while you're scrolling the modal.

Comment: Thank you for comment. I solve the issue.

Answer (score 7):

Solution is very easy:

```
$('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-dialog').height() }, 500);
```

Answer (score 1):

The other solution did not work for me however it was close.

Here is what worked for me:

```
$('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-content').height() }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modification of the working answer, this will scroll to the bottom of the modal. The other option did not get to the bottom but stopped at the middle.

```
    $("#modal .modal-body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-body').prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow');
```

Remember to replace '#modal' with the Name of your own modal.

You might also want to make sure it works when you open the modal

```
   <script>
      $('#modal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
      $("#modal .modal-body").animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-body').prop("scrollHeight")}, 'slow');
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: it works if modal contains ```.modal-dialog-scrollable``` class

Answer (score 0):

For Scrolling of Bootstrap modal window to bottom,
here is what worked for me:

```
$('#modal .modal-body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-body').offset().top }, 'slow');
```

Answer (score 0):

With the new Bootstrap V5.x, you can now use:

```js
jQuery('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('#modal.modal-content').height() }, 'slow');
```