# Bootstrap modal scroll to bottom of modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

How can you scroll to the bottom of a modal? I'm using angular-ui bootstrap. [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xJRIKudIij7B7MLN6evD?p=preview)

I've tried: (per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/270612/scroll-to-bottom-of-div))

```
var ele = $('.modal-dialog')
ele.scrollTop = ele.scrollHeight
```

and also (per this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42994729/scrolling-of-modal-window-bootstrap-to-bottom))

```
$('#modal').animate({ scrollTop: $('#modal .modal-dialog').height() }, 500);
```

[Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/xJRIKudIij7B7MLN6evD?p=preview)

Comment: Don't use jQuery, try [this example](https://plnkr.co/edit/rXnUyv6LBD87JQGZvXeP?p=preview), it uses `$anchorScroll`

Comment: thanks @AlekseySolovey feel free to answer and i'll accept